# Style my text inputs just like a password input

Tags: css, angularjs, passwords, credit-card, masking

I'm developing a webapp (angularjs) that requires user to input a credit card. The first 12 digits of the credit card must be invisible to user, so currently right now I'm using password inputs to achieve this.

[image]

The problem with this is that Chrome thinks that I'm really writing a password, so it gives me the option to use/change my stored credentials for this website:

[image]

So I want to know **if there is a CSS way or angular plugin that I can use in order to make my text inputs looks like password for the user.**

Comment: you can use this input.classname{
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
} but i don't think this will work in IE browser.

Comment: Will try. Dont worry about IE :)

Comment: Works like a charm. However if you want it for all browsers you can use: https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML5 Input Type Password**, like this:

```css
.pass, .regular{
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Credit Card:</p>
 <input type="password" class="pass">
 <input type="password" class="pass">
 <input type="password" class="pass">
 <input type="text" class="regular">
</div>
```

Here a link to an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_password).

Comment: This is explicitly what OP is trying to avoid using.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use HTML input type password because it tries to use my credentials for the site for autofill, so I went with Nirav Parmar answer and used: -webkit-text-security: disc;

However, this only works for chrome, for all browsers you can use this plugin that creates a font based only of circles or dots.
https://github.com/noppa/text-security